# Jquery Datatable with MsExcel Export issue on number formatting

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

The long number was transformed to a whole number in the Jquery datatable export to Microsoft Excel. ways to stop this

If I had a number like 1234567891011121314, after exporting this in Excel, it shows 123456789101112000 like this. I need to export datatable records to msExcel without using Excel's auto number formatting.

Comment: Show your code. We cant guess what you are doing and give an answer.

Comment: You will have to force this column to be a string then. Excel autoformats columns by default.

Comment: {
            "extend": 'excel',
            "text": '<i class="bi bi-file-earmark-spreadsheet" ></i>  Excel',
            "titleAttr": 'Excel',
            "exportOptions": {
                'columns': [0,1,2]
            },
            "customize": function(xlsx) {
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
            $('row c[r^="B"]', sheet).each(function() {
                var cell = $(this);
                cell.attr('t', 'str'); // Treat cell as a string
            });
        },
            "action": newexportaction
        },

Comment: cant read the code in comment. Add that in your question

Comment: @nice_dev then how i export this number with excel whole number transformation

Comment: As per @nice_dev said, you can add a backtick 「\`」before the long number to become a string. Or add macro to your exported excel

Comment: Caution with backticks though, if you use the value of the cell with backticks, (use in formula, import to a software) it will also fetch the backticks and may cause errors.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth I tried using this form of apostrophe, however the apostrophe appeared with a number that wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: Edit your question to include what you tried. Again we cannot guess what you did.

Comment: @vignesh Can you show sample snippet?